# How to filter the contents by manually typing number and filtering using angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have totally 4 fields to filter the table contents. If i put 2 values in filter section it works, if i add one more field in that not even one works. Can anyone help me to filter the contents, based on email and phone number as well.

[image]
HTML:
The upper part of code for using filter data:

```
<ng-select [options]="name" [(ngModel)]="filter.name"></ng-select>
      <ng-select [options]="email" [(ngModel)]="filter.email"></ng-select>
      <input type="number" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==10) return false;" class="form-textbox input-text" [(ngModel)]="filter.phone_number">
      <ng-select [options]="pinAddress" [(ngModel)]="filter.address"></ng-select>
```

pipe used to filter the table:

```
<tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let pin of pins | pinfilter:filter">
            <td>{{pin.name}}</td>
            <td>{{pin.description}}</td>
            <td>{{pin.address}}</td>
            <td>{{pin.website}}</td>
            <td>{{pin.phone_number}}</td>
            <td>{{pin.email}}</td>
            <td>{{pin.comments}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

TS:

```
filter.pipe.ts:
/* Tutorial filter to write filter functions for Tutorial*/
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

export class NewPin { 
  public _id:number;
  public user_id:number;
  public name:string;  
  public address:string;
  public phone_number:string;
  public email:string;
  public comments:boolean;
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'pinfilter',
  pure: false
})

export class PinPipe implements PipeTransform { 
  transform(items: NewPin[], filter: NewPin): NewPin[] { 
    if (!items || (!filter.name && !filter.address)) { 
      return items; 
    } 
      return items.filter((item: NewPin) => this.applyFilter(item, filter)); 
  } 

  applyFilter(user: NewPin, filter: NewPin): boolean {
    console.log(filter);
    if (filter.name && filter.address) { 
      if (filter.name == user.name && filter.address == user.address) { 
        return true 
      } else { 
        return false 
      } 
    } else if (filter.name) { 
        if (filter.name == user.name) { 
          return true 
    } else { 
        return false 
      }  
    } else if (filter.address) { 
      if (filter.address == user.address) { 
        return true 
      } else { 
        return false 
      } 
    } else { 
      return true 
    } 
  } 
}
```

component.ts:

```
public filter: NewPin = new NewPin();
```

Comment: What is `ng-select` ? Where do you use your pipe ? What does your data look like ? What is your goal ? Why isn't there 4 inputs ? Don't give just a bit of code if you want help. Either give a [mcve] or your whole code so that we can try it, and find your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response, ya i will update the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your applyFilter function so that it will check all the filter properties against the data being filtered.

I would also suggest making it a little simpler in structure, something like this:

```
  applyFilter(user: NewPin, filter: NewPin): boolean {
    console.log(filter);
    // check all the filters
    if (filter.name && filter.name != user.name) { 
        return false; 
    } 
    if (filter.address && filter.address != user.address) { 
        return false 
    }  
    if (filter.email && filter.email != user.email) { 
        return false; 
    }  
    if (filter.phone_number && filter.phone_number != user.phone_number) { 
        return false;
    }  
    // if the user passes all the filters, show it
    return true; 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it is not working with phone number, can ypou pls help me to solve that

Comment: It looks like phone_number is a number, while the data may be a string. Check if that is the case (debug), then you will need to change the comparison to take that into account